# Add Ribbon Button to DispForm

Tags: ribbon

It tried to add a custom button to the DispForm of a element. The Button is visible but not enabled. I tried to add a simple EnableScript but it does not work.

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction
  Id="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.AddAButton"
  RegistrationType="List"
  RegistrationId="100"
  Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition
         Location="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Actions.Controls._children">
          <Button
           Id="Ribbon.ListForm.Display.Actions.Controls.AddAButton"
           Alt="Show HelloWorld Alert"

           Command="ShowHelloWorldCommand"
           LabelText="HelloWorld"
           TemplateAlias="o1"/>
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler 
         Command="ShowHelloWorldCommand"
         CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello World');" />
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `EnabledScript` in your XML definition. It should look like this:

```
<CommandUIHandlers>
   <CommandUIHandler 
   Command="ShowHelloWorldCommand"
   CommandAction="javascript:alert('Hello World');"
   EnabledScript="javascript:return true;" />
</CommandUIHandlers>
```

If that doesn't help try setting the scope of your feature to Web instead of Site.

Comment: I add this Command: EnabledScript="javascript:function enableButton() { return true; } enableButton();" I forgot to call the function.

Answer (score -1):

How about following this solution on adding a button on ribbon :

http://www.abelsolutions.com/totm/creating-a-custom-action-in-2-steps-with-sharepoint-designer/